# how to copy all files and folder outside the build context/ folder where dockerfile resides in dockerfile

Tags: build, dockerfile

Assuming my project structure looks like this:

```
/parent_directory
  ├── build
  │   └── Dockerfile
      |----.dockerignore
  ├── file1
  ├── file2
  └── ...
```

I am trying to build the dockerfile and have all file1,file2 and everything from the parent_directory so when I run the docker command as below

```
cd /path/to/parent_directory
docker build -t your-image-name .
```

I get the error that it cannot find Dockerfile and when I adjust the command to be as below

```
cd /path/to/parent_directory
docker build ./build
```

I get only files from the build directory and not from the root directory
so when I adjust it to be like as below:

```
cd /path/to/parent_directory
docker build -t your-image-name -f ./build/Dockerfile .
```

then I get error like

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 3.616MB
Error response from daemon: unexpected EOF
```

and it tries to copy all the files and even when I remove the COPY . . in the docker file it still give me the same error which tells me that there is something wrong with the build context. I am wondering if there is any better way to do this ,also I have tried to dockerignore some files from the root directory too
and my Dockerfile looks like as below:

```
# Use the base image you need
FROM some-base-image

# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy all files from the parent directory to the current directory in the container
COPY . .

# Rest of your Dockerfile...
```